# Most busy times in space launches by decade?

Tags: launch, history, statistics

If anyone has the curiosity and time and possibility to run the scripts, I think it's interesting to see the most busy day, week, month and year, by decade.

Most busy week of 1960s then most busy week of 1970s then 1980s and so on.

The scripts are found in the accepted answer of this question

[What was the most busy week in space launches?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/45696/what-was-the-most-busy-week-in-space-launches)

[Number of satellites launched by decade?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/48364/number-of-satellites-launched-by-decade)

Comment: Do we have sufficient info to do the same for launch Payload mass and for Payload count, not just count of launches? (because recently we tend to launch less rockets, but larger, containing a multitude of satellites each)

Comment: No idea,  try asking @JonHeller

Comment: @MarvinKitfox JSR doesn't have information about payload mass, but it does have data for launch vehicle LEO and GTO capacity. Unfortunately that data has lots of empty or zero values. Take a look at the LAUNCH_VEHICLE table in the database described below. Changing the launch count to satellite count is pretty easy, just add this code to the end of line 7 in my query below: ` join satellite on launch.launch_id = satellite.launch_id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Results

Below are the most-busy time periods based on the the JSR Launch Database database described [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/48390/33395). I checked a few results with Carlos' answer and they seem to match.

```
THE_DAY    THE_WEEK THE_MONTH THE_YEAR THE_DECADE LAUNCH_COUNT
---------- -------- --------- -------- ---------- ------------
4/26/1962                                         3           

           1985-W43                               7           

                    1971-12                       17          

                              1984                128         

                                       1950       23          
                                       1960       838         
                                       1970       1151        
                                       1980       1145        
                                       1990       837         
                                       2000       628         
                                       2010       600         

10/4/1957                              1950       1           
4/26/1962                              1960       3           
4/8/1970                               1970       3           
5/26/1983                              1980       3           
2/28/1990                              1990       3           
12/21/2005                             2000       3           
6/15/2010                              2010       3           

           1957-W40                    1950       1           
           1962-W17                    1960       6           
           1970-W15                    1970       6           
           1985-W43                    1980       7           
           1993-W25                    1990       6           
           2000-W28                    2000       5           
           2015-W13                    2010       6           

                    1959-08            1950       3           
                    1965-12            1960       15          
                    1971-12            1970       17          
                    1983-04            1980       17          
                    1990-04            1990       14          
                    2000-10            2000       12          
                    2014-12            2010       15          

                              1959     1950       13          
                              1967     1960       124         
                              1976     1970       126         
                              1984     1980       128         
                              1990     1990       115         
                              2000     2000       81          
                              2014     2010       89
```

The above results are not complete since I removed a huge number of ties. Run the below query to see the full results.

### Query

This query is quite complicated, but it lets you do a huge amount of grouping in one statement and lets you easily change the input conditions. (I manually adjusted the above results to remove duplicates and to make a better looking order.)

```
--Most busy times in space launches, per day/week/month/year, and also
--per day/week/month/year and by decade.
with launches as
(
    --#1: Choose the relevant statuses and categories to use in the rest of the query.
    select *
    from launch
    where launch_status = 'success'
        and launch_category in ('deep space', 'orbital')
)
--#6: Only choose the highest ranks.
select *
from
(
    --#5: Rank the different groups.
    select counts.*, dense_rank() over (partition by grouping_id, the_decade order by launch_count desc) the_rank
    from
    (
        --#4: Count per different grouping.
        select
            the_day, the_week, the_month, the_year, the_decade,
            grouping_id(the_day, the_week, the_month, the_year, the_decade) grouping_id,
            count(launches.launch_date) launch_count
        from
        (
            --#3: Date dimension for different date groupings.
            select
                the_day,
                to_char(trunc(the_day, 'iw'), 'YYYY-"W"iw') the_week,
                to_char(trunc(the_day, 'iw'), 'YYYY-MM-DD') week_start,
                to_char(trunc(the_day, 'iw')+6, 'YYYY-MM-DD') week_end,
                to_char(the_day, 'YYYY-MM') the_month,
                to_char(the_day, 'YYYY') the_year,
                trunc(to_char(the_day, 'YYYY')/10)*10 the_decade
            from
            (
                --#2: All days in the data set.
                select trunc((select min(launch_date) from launches) + level - 1) the_day
                from dual
                connect by level <= (select ceil(max(launch_date) - min(launch_date)) from launches)
                order by the_day
            )
        ) dates
        left join launches
            on dates.the_day = trunc(launches.launch_date)
        group by grouping sets((the_day), (the_week), (the_month), (the_year), (the_decade)
            ,(the_decade, the_year), (the_decade, the_month), (the_decade, the_week), (the_decade, the_day))
        order by grouping_id, the_decade, the_day, the_week, the_month, the_year
    ) counts
    order by grouping_id, the_rank
)
where the_rank = 1
order by grouping_id, the_decade, the_day, the_week, the_month, the_year;
```

Comment: Great answer again, thanks! Meanwhile I started another question, canyou take a look please? https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/48364/number-of-satellites-launched-by-decade -ready to put a bounty

Comment: Looks like 2014 has 92 launches and 88 of them are succesfull

Answer (score 8):

I have an Excel spreadsheet that pivots the data from JSR.  I include all launches intended for orbit (earth or otherwise), both successful and unsuccessful.  Here is my take at your request.  Coming up with a good way of displaying within the StackExchange  limitations is not easy.

**Busiest Months**

The specific busiest months, by decade were:

```
50s - Aug 58 (7)
60s - Dec 65, Apr 68 (16)
70s - Dec 71 (20)
80s - Jun 82 (18)
90s - Apr 90, Aug 90 (15)
00s - Oct 00 (12)
10s - Dec 14, Dec 18, Dec 19 (15)
20s - Jul 20 (14)
```

Table shows total number of launches for each calendar month.

```
+-------+-----+------+------+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-------+
| Month | 50s |  60s |  70s |  80s | 90s | 00s | 10s | 20s | Total |
+-------+-----+------+------+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-------+
|   1   |  1  |  55  |  74  |  84  |  54 |  30 |  53 |  7  |  358  |
+-------+-----+------+------+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-------+
|   2   |  4  |  75  |  86  |  96  |  74 |  49 |  56 |  9  |  449  |
+-------+-----+------+------+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-------+
|   3   |  4  |  89  |  90  |  102 |  63 |  47 |  66 |  8  |  469  |
+-------+-----+------+------+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-------+
|   4   |  4  |  98  |  111 |  95  |  86 |  62 |  66 |  5  |  527  |
+-------+-----+------+------+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-------+
|   5   |  2  |  77  |  105 |  104 |  70 |  54 |  67 |  9  |  488  |
+-------+-----+------+------+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-------+
|   6   |  5  |  92  |  124 |  119 |  60 |  65 |  77 |  7  |  549  |
+-------+-----+------+------+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-------+
|   7   |  3  |  80  |  105 |  99  |  78 |  46 |  72 |  14 |  497  |
+-------+-----+------+------+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-------+
|   8   |  11 |  91  |  98  |  108 |  95 |  53 |  64 |  7  |  527  |
+-------+-----+------+------+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-------+
|   9   |  5  |  78  |  101 |  121 |  68 |  67 |  86 |  10 |  536  |
+-------+-----+------+------+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-------+
|   10  |  7  |  104 |  117 |  92  |  76 |  69 |  76 |     |  541  |
+-------+-----+------+------+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-------+
|   11  |  5  |  87  |  85  |  77  |  74 |  47 |  90 |     |  465  |
+-------+-----+------+------+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-------+
|   12  |  4  |  96  |  136 |  96  |  93 |  75 | 116 |     |  616  |
+-------+-----+------+------+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-------+
| Total |  55 | 1022 | 1232 | 1193 | 891 | 664 | 889 |  76 |  6022 |
+-------+-----+------+------+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-------+
```

[image: Launches per Calendar Month]

**Busiest Weeks**

The specific busiest weeks, by decade were (week number/year):

```
50s - w35/58 (4)
60s - w38/66 (7)
70s - w49/21 (8)
80s - w43/85 (8)
90s - w26/93, w45/94 (6)
00s - w07/00, w11/08 (5)
10s - w13/15, w41/17, w2/18, w49/18 (6)
20s - w30/20, w36/20 (5)
```

Table shows top 5 calendar weeks (1-52) per decade.  In case of a tie at the bottom of the top 5 range I only show the first X weeks in the tie (e.g. the not displayed row #6 may have the same count as the displayed row #5). Busiest week across the entire space age is week #51 - the rush to launch before Christmas.

```
+-------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----------+
| Rank  | 50s | 60s | 70s | 80s | 90s | 00s | 10s | 20s | Space Age |
+-------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----------+
|   1   | 35  | 51  | 51  | 36  | 14  | 43  | 33  | 30  | 51        |
+-------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----------+
|   2   | 41  | 43  | 26  | 25  | 35  | 17  | 29  | 36  | 21        |
+-------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----------+
|   3   | 49  | 17  | 21  | 21  | 7   | 52  | 28  | 27  | 52        |
+-------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----------+
|   4   | 26  | 42  | 30  | 32  | 51  | 37  | 28  | 7   | 39        |
+-------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----------+
|   5   | 45  | 12  | 42  | 38  | 52  | 42  | 24  | 8   | 26        |
+-------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----------+
```

[image: Launches per Calendar Week]

**Busiest Days**

The specific busiest days, by decade were:

```
50s - 11-Oct-58 (2)
60s - 26-Apr-62 (4)
70s - 15 different days with 3 launches
80s - 10 different days with 3 launches
90s - 7 different days with 3 launches
00s - 13-Mar-00, 21-Dec-05  (3)
10s - 7 different days with 3 launches
20s - 12 different days with 2 launches
```

Table shows top 10 calendar days (1-366) per decade.  In case of a tie at the bottom of the top 10 range I only show the first X days in the tie (e.g. the not displayed row #11 may have the same count as the displayed row #10).  There clearly is a lull around New Year.  The lull around day 122 is harder to explain, it is too late for the Easter holidays.  Across the entire Space Age day 355 is the busiest (launch in time to get everyone home for Christmas?

```
+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----------+
| Rank | 50s | 60s | 70s | 80s | 90s | 00s | 10s | 20s | Space Age |
+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----------+
|   1  | 277 | 116 | 178 | 271 | 324 | 355 | 272 | 186 |    355    |
+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----------+
|   2  | 284 | 144 | 350 | 191 | 356 | 241 | 353 | 256 |    116    |
+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----------+
|   3  | 340 | 297 |  97 | 169 | 242 | 268 | 337 | 212 |    178    |
+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----------+
|   4  | 255 | 355 | 204 |  50 |  81 | 303 | 324 |  16 |    350    |
+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----------+
|   5  | 227 | 339 |  20 | 246 | 336 | 116 | 268 | 165 |    135    |
+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----------+
|   6  | 290 | 167 | 259 |  83 | 360 | 288 | 325 |  40 |    361    |
+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----------+
|   7  |  59 | 235 | 289 | 135 | 269 | 110 | 357 | 205 |    353    |
+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----------+
|   8  | 236 | 156 | 137 | 361 | 214 | 124 | 351 |  76 |    231    |
+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----------+
|   9  |  62 | 350 | 161 | 215 | 115 | 252 | 156 | 247 |    140    |
+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----------+
|  10  | 269 |  84 | 325 |  16 |  59 | 159 |  32 | 100 |    324    |
+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----------+
```

[image: Launches per Calendar Day]

Comment: Thanks this is very interesting. I think nobody will give a better answer so you will get the bounty anyways. But can you provide another answer with the specific days, weeks and months that tank the highest instead of combine per decade? Like the answer to the other question, but separated by decades

Comment: For example the most busy month in 1970s was 1971-12 with 17 launches and in the 1980s it was 1983-04 with 17

Comment: I see.  I misunderstood your question.  Ironically finding the specifics will be a bit more manual in Excel, but I should be able to pull those out once I have some more time.

Comment: @JoeJobs - I added the data you requested.  For peak days  there is too many to add, and right now I have to look them up manually in Excel.

Comment: 1971-04 has 20 launches instead of the 17 listed by the answer to the other question. Did you include suborbital space launches too?

Comment: It's Dec 1971 (Not April) that had the most launches with 20 and it includes 3 failures - which gives you your 17.  For this kind of research which is trying to ascertain cadence and frequency failures must be counted.