# Number of satellites launched by decade?

Tags: launch, artificial-satellite, statistics

How many satellites were launched each decade?

Including satellites of Mars Moon Venus Sun etc

Similar question

[Number of satellites launched per year?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/48375/number-of-satellites-launched-per-year)

[Most busy times in space launches by decade?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/45911/most-busy-times-in-space-launches-by-decade)

Comment: @JonHeller - pinging for hopefully getting an nice scripted answer. I can put a bounty on it also

Comment: From [meta FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7931/303080) click [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/303080) From there you'll see that the "magic @" won't send a notification to someone unless they've already posted a comment here. Stack Exchange isn't wired for actual "pinging". However if you know of a post by another user (or a post *with a comment by that user*) that is related to this question, in Space SE it is usually considered acceptable to leave a short comment there mentioning this related new question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Number of satellites launched per decade:

```
DECADE  SATELLITE_COUNT
------  ---------------
1950                 33
1960               2323
1970               4504
1980               5744
1990               3936
2000               2309
2010               2341
```

The results are once again from the JSR 2017 report and are based on this query:

```
--Satellites launched per decade (excluding debris).
select trunc(to_char(launch_date, 'YYYY')/10)*10 decade, count(*) satellite_count
from launch
join satellite
    on launch.launch_id = satellite.launch_id
where official_name not like 'deb %'
group by trunc(to_char(launch_date, 'YYYY')/10)*10
order by decade;
```

[This answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/48390/33395) provides information about how to run the query yourself. Hopefully that information is convenient enough that you can write queries and answer your own questions - let me know if the site is not working or if you have ideas for improving it.

Comment: Awesome again! Can you please do the same by year? https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/48375/number-of-satellites-launched-per-year

Comment: It might be worth noting that around half of that are marked as debris. According to [the list](https://planet4589.org/space/log/satcat.txt) I found 3462 alone are debris of [Fengyun-1C ](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fengyun-1C) which arteficially inflates the number of satellites launched in 1990. Maybe you should filter out all satellites that start with "deb".

Comment: Also bear in mind that many launches put up more than one satellite so even excluding the debris the number of actual satellites is a lot less than the number of launches. For example, on 18 August a single Falcon launch carried fifty-eight Starlink satellites and three SkySats.

Comment: @Christoph Thank you for the suggestion. I removed 'deb %' from the results and the numbers look quite different now!

Comment: Oops! I should have said in my comment above that the number of actual satellites is a lot MORE than the number of launches. Can't see how to edit it, but I'm sure you knew what I meant.

Comment: @JonHeller - I've put a bounty on the sister question - by year - https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/48375/number-of-satellites-launched-per-year - can you take a look please?