# Number of launches by year, by country

Tags: launch, statistics

This is a question about how many orbital launches made each year China, then the same question for India and so on for every country that made orbital launches

Additionaly, is there any country that reached space (100 km) but not orbit?

Similar question:

- [What is the number of launches by year?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/48414/what-is-the-number-of-launches-by-year)

Comment: I'm only going to answer your first question. The second is different enough I would suggest asking it as a stand alone question.

Comment: That is still good, thanks. After you post the answer I will post the India question

Answer (score 4):

Wikipedia maintains a really good set of pages for each year, showing the launch statistics per country for that given year. The page for 2020 is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2020_in_spaceflight#Orbital_launch_statistics .

Answer (score 2):

While waiting for a real answer I will fill some numbers here:

China

- Launches - succesfull - failures - partial failures

- 2019 - 34 - 32 - 2 - 0
- 2018 - 39 - 38 - 1 - 0
- 2017 - 18 - 16 - 1 - 1
- 2016 - 22 - 20 - 1 - 1
- 2015 - 19 - 19 - 0 - 0
- 2014 - 16 - 16 - 0 - 0
- 2013 - 15 - 14 - 1 - 0
- 2012 - 19 - 19 - 0 - 0
- 2011 - 19 - 18 - 1 - 0
- 2010 - 15 - 15 - 0 - 0
- 2009 - 6 - 5 - 0 - 1
- 2008 - 11 - 11 - 0 - 0
- 2007 - 10 - 10 - 0 - 0
- 2006 - 6 - 6 - 0 - 0
- 2005 - 5 - 5 - 0 - 0
- 2004 - 8 - 8 - 0 - 0
- 2003 - 7 - 6 - 1 - 0
- 2002 - 5 - 4 - 1 - 0
- 2001 - 1 - 1 - 0 - 0
- 2000 -
- 1999 -
- 1998 -
- 1997 -
- 1996 -
- 1995 -
- 1994 -
- 1993 -
- 1992 -
- 1991 -
- 1990 -
- 1989 -
- 1988 -
- 1987 -
- 1986 -
- 1985 -
- 1984 -
- 1983 -
- 1982 -
- 1981 -
- 1980 -
- 1979 -
- 1978 -
- 1977 -
- 1976 -
- 1975 -
- 1974 -
- 1973 -
- 1972 -
- 1971 -
- 1970 -
- 1969 -
- 1968 -
- 1967 -
- 1966 -
- 1965 -
- 1964 -
- 1963 -
- 1962 -
- 1961 -
- 1960 -

India

- 2019 - 6 - 6 - 0 - 0
- 2018 - 7 - 7 - 0 - 0
- 2017 - 5 - 4 - 1 - 0
- 2016 - 7 - 7 - 0 - 0
- 2015 - 5 - 5 - 0 - 0
- 2014 - 4 - 4 - 0 - 0
- 2013 - 3 - 3 - 0 - 0
- 2012 - 2 - 2 - 0 - 0
- 2011 - 3 - 3 - 0 - 0
- 2010 - 3 - 1 - 2 - 0
- 2009 - 2 - 2 - 0 - 0
- 2008 - 3 - 3 - 0 - 0
- 2007 - 3 - 2 - 0 - 1
- 2006 - 1 - 0 - 1 - 0
- 2005 - 1 - 1 - 0 - 0
- 2004 - 1 - 1 - 0 - 0
- 2003 - 2 - 2 - 0 - 0
- 2002 - 1 - 1 - 0 - 0
- 2001 - 2 - 2 - 0 - 0
- 2000 -
- 1999 -
- 1998 -
- 1997 -
- 1996 -
- 1995 -
- 1994 -
- 1993 -
- 1992 -
- 1991 -
- 1990 -
- 1989 -
- 1988 -
- 1987 -
- 1986 -
- 1985 -
- 1984 -
- 1983 -
- 1982 -
- 1981 -
- 1980 -
- 1979 -
- 1978 -
- 1977 -
- 1976 -
- 1975 -
- 1974 -
- 1973 -
- 1972 -
- 1971 -
- 1970 -
- 1969 -
- 1968 -
- 1967 -
- 1966 -
- 1965 -
- 1964 -
- 1963 -
- 1962 -
- 1961 -
- 1960 -

USA

- 2019 - 27 - 27 - 0 - 0
- 2018 - 34 - 34 - 0 - 0
- 2017 - 30 - 29 - 1 - 0
- 2016 - 22 - 22 - 0 - 0
- 2015 - 20 - 18 - 2 - 0
- 2014 - 23 - 22 - 1 - 0
- 2013 - 19 - 19 - 0 - 0
- 2012 - 13 - 12 - 0 - 1
- 2011 - 18 - 17 - 1 - 0
- 2010 - 15 - 15 - 0 - 0
- 2009 - 24 - 23 - 1 - 0
- 2008 - 15 - 14 - 1 - 0
- 2007 - 19 - 17 - 1 - 1
- 2006 - 18 - 17 - 1 - 0
- 2005 - 12 - 12 - 0 - 0
- 2004 - 16 - 15 - 0 - 1
- 2003 - 23 - 22 - 1 - 0
- 2002 - 17 - 15 - 1 - 1
- 2001 - 22 - 20 - 1 - 1
- 2000 -
- 1999 -
- 1998 -
- 1997 -
- 1996 -
- 1995 -
- 1994 -
- 1993 -
- 1992 -
- 1991 -
- 1990 -
- 1989 -
- 1988 -
- 1987 -
- 1986 -
- 1985 -
- 1984 -
- 1983 -
- 1982 -
- 1981 -
- 1980 -
- 1979 -
- 1978 -
- 1977 -
- 1976 -
- 1975 -
- 1974 -
- 1973 -
- 1972 -
- 1971 -
- 1970 -
- 1969 -
- 1968 -
- 1967 -
- 1966 -
- 1965 -
- 1964 -
- 1963 -
- 1962 -
- 1961 -
- 1960 -

Europe

- 2019 - 6 - 5 - 1 - 0
- 2018 - 8 - 7 - 0 - 1
- 2017 - 9 - 9 - 0 - 0
- 2016 - 9 - 9 - 0 - 0
- 2015 - 9 - 9 - 0 - 0
- 2014 - 7 - 7 - 0 - 0
- 2013 - 5 - 5 - 0 - 0
- 2012 - 8 - 8 - 0 - 0
- 2011 - 5 - 5 - 0 - 0
- 2010 - 6 - 6 - 0 - 0
- 2009 - 7 - 7 - 0 - 0
- 2008 - 6 - 6 - 0 - 0
- 2007 - 6 - 6 - 0 - 0
- 2006 - 5 - 5 - 0 - 0
- 2005 - 5 - 5 - 0 - 0
- 2004 - 3 - 3 - 0 - 0
- 2003 - 4 - 4 - 0 - 0
- 2002 - 12 - 11 - 1 - 0
- 2001 - 8 - 7 - 0 - 1
- 2000 -
- 1999 -
- 1998 -
- 1997 -
- 1996 -
- 1995 -
- 1994 -
- 1993 -
- 1992 -
- 1991 -
- 1990 -
- 1989 -
- 1988 -
- 1987 -
- 1986 -
- 1985 -
- 1984 -
- 1983 -
- 1982 -
- 1981 -
- 1980 -
- 1979 -
- 1978 -
- 1977 -
- 1976 -
- 1975 -
- 1974 -
- 1973 -
- 1972 -
- 1971 -
- 1970 -
- 1969 -
- 1968 -
- 1967 -
- 1966 -
- 1965 -
- 1964 -
- 1963 -
- 1962 -
- 1961 -
- 1960 -

Russia

- 2019 - 25 - 25 - 0 - 0
- 2018 - 20 - 19 - 1 - 0
- 2017 - 20 - 18 - 1 - 1
- 2016 - 19 - 18 - 1 - 0
- 2015 - 27 - 24 - 2 - 1
- 2014 - 34 - 31 - 1 - 2
- 2013 - 31 - 28 - 2 - 1
- 2012 - 26 - 24 - 1 - 1
- 2011 - 29 - 25 - 4 - 0
- 2010 - 28 - 27 - 1 - 0
- 2009 - 27 - 26 - 1 - 0
- 2008 - 24 - 23 - 0 - 1
- 2007 - 22 - 21 - 1 - 0
- 2006 - 22 - 21 - 1 - 0
- 2005 - 25 - 22 - 3 - 0
- 2004 - 18 - 18 - 0 - 0
- 2003 - 21 - 21 - 0 - 0
- 2002 - 24 - 22 - 2 - 0
- 2001 - 18 - 17 - 1 - 0
- 2000 -
- 1999 -
- 1998 -
- 1997 -
- 1996 -
- 1995 -
- 1994 -
- 1993 -
- 1992 -
- 1991 -
- 1990 -
- 1989 -
- 1988 -
- 1987 -
- 1986 -
- 1985 -
- 1984 -
- 1983 -
- 1982 -
- 1981 -
- 1980 -
- 1979 -
- 1978 -
- 1977 -
- 1976 -
- 1975 -
- 1974 -
- 1973 -
- 1972 -
- 1971 -
- 1970 -
- 1969 -
- 1968 -
- 1967 -
- 1966 -
- 1965 -
- 1964 -
- 1963 -
- 1962 -
- 1961 -
- 1960 -

Japan

- 2019 - 2 - 2 - 0 - 0
- 2018 - 6 - 6 - 0 - 0
- 2017 - 7 - 6 - 1 - 0
- 2016 - 4 - 4 - 0 - 0
- 2015 - 4 - 4 - 0 - 0
- 2014 - 4 - 4 - 0 - 0
- 2013 - 3 - 3 - 0 - 0
- 2012 - 2 - 2 - 0 - 0
- 2011 - 3 - 3 - 0 - 0
- 2010 - 2 - 2 - 0 - 0
- 2009 - 3 - 3 - 0 - 0
- 2008 - 1 - 1 - 0 - 0
- 2007 - 2 - 2 - 0 - 0
- 2006 - 6 - 6 - 0 - 0
- 2005 - 2 - 2 - 0 - 0
- 2004 - 0 - 0 - 0 - 0
- 2003 - 3 - 2 - 1 - 0
- 2002 - 3 - 3 - 0 - 0
- 2001 - 3 - 2 - 1 - 0
- 2000 -
- 1999 -
- 1998 -
- 1997 -
- 1996 -
- 1995 -
- 1994 -
- 1993 -
- 1992 -
- 1991 -
- 1990 -
- 1989 -
- 1988 -
- 1987 -
- 1986 -
- 1985 -
- 1984 -
- 1983 -
- 1982 -
- 1981 -
- 1980 -
- 1979 -
- 1978 -
- 1977 -
- 1976 -
- 1975 -
- 1974 -
- 1973 -
- 1972 -
- 1971 -
- 1970 -
- 1969 -
- 1968 -
- 1967 -
- 1966 -
- 1965 -
- 1964 -
- 1963 -
- 1962 -
- 1961 -
- 1960 -

Iran

- 2019 - 2 - 0 - 2 - 0
- 2108 - 0 - 0 - 0 - 0
- 2017 - 1 - 0 - 1 - 0
- 2016 - 0 - 0 - 0 - 0
- 2015 - 1 - 1 - 0 - 0
- 2013 - 2 - 1 - 1 - 0
- 2011 - 1 - 1 - 0 - 0
- 2009 - 1 - 1 - 0 - 0
- 2008 - 1 - 0 - 1 - 0

Ukraine

- 2017 - 1 - 1 - 0 - 0
- 2015 - 2 - 2 - 0 - 0
- 2014 - 3 - 3 - 0 - 0
- 2013 - 4 - 4 - 0 - 0
- 2012 - 3 - 3 - 0 - 0
- 2011 - 6 - 6 - 0 - 0
- 2010 - 3 - 3 - 0 - 0
- 2009 - 6 - 6 - 0 - 0
- 2008 - 8 - 8 - 0 - 0
- 2007 - 5 - 4 - 1 - 0
- 2006 - 8 - 7 - 1 - 0
- 2005 - 5 - 5 - 0 - 0
- 2004 - 7 - 5 - 0 - 2
- 2003 - 3 - 3 - 0 - 0
- 2002 - 2 - 2 - 0 - 0
- 2001 - 6 - 6 - 0 - 0

South Korea

- 2013 - 1 - 1 - 0 - 0
- 2010 - 1 - 0 - 1 - 0
- 2009 - 1 - 0 - 1 - 0

North Korea

- 2016 - 1 - 1 - 0 - 0
- 2012 - 2 - 1 - 1 - 0
- 2009 - 1 - 0 - 1 - 0
- 2006 - 1 - 0 - 1 - 0

Israel

- 2016 - 1 - 1 - 0 - 0
- 2014 - 1 - 1 - 0 - 0
- 2010 - 1 - 1 - 0 - 0
- 2007 - 1 - 1 - 0 - 0
- 2004 - 1 - 0 - 1 - 0
- 2002 - 1 - 1 - 0 - 0

Brazil

- 2003 - 1 - 0 - 1 - 0

Taiwan

- 2001 - 1 - 0 - 1 - 0

The sources are pages like this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2001_in_spaceflight#Orbital_launch_summary

Unfortunately they contain no such data for 2000 and before

There is also this link

https://aerospace.csis.org/data/space-environment-total-launches-by-country/

Answer (score 1):

This is the data for China:

| YEAR | LAUNCHES | SUCCESS | FAILURE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020 | 37 | 33 | 4 |
| 2019 | 34 | 32 | 2 |
| 2018 | 39 | 38 | 1 |
| 2017 | 18 | 16 | 2 |
| 2016 | 22 | 21 | 1 |
| 2015 | 19 | 19 | 0 |
| 2014 | 16 | 16 | 0 |
| 2013 | 15 | 14 | 1 |
| 2012 | 19 | 19 | 0 |
| 2011 | 19 | 18 | 1 |
| 2010 | 15 | 15 | 0 |
| 2009 | 6 | 5 | 1 |
| 2008 | 11 | 11 | 0 |
| 2007 | 10 | 10 | 0 |
| 2006 | 6 | 6 | 0 |
| 2005 | 6 | 5 | 1 |
| 2004 | 8 | 8 | 0 |
| 2003 | 7 | 6 | 1 |
| 2002 | 5 | 4 | 1 |
| 2001 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2000 | 5 | 5 | 0 |
| 1999 | 4 | 4 | 0 |
| 1998 | 6 | 6 | 0 |
| 1997 | 6 | 6 | 0 |
| 1996 | 4 | 2 | 2 |
| 1995 | 3 | 2 | 1 |
| 1994 | 5 | 5 | 0 |
| 1993 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1992 | 4 | 3 | 1 |
| 1991 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1990 | 5 | 5 | 0 |
| 1988 | 4 | 4 | 0 |
| 1987 | 2 | 2 | 0 |
| 1986 | 2 | 2 | 0 |
| 1985 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1984 | 3 | 3 | 0 |
| 1983 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1982 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1981 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1979 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 1978 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1976 | 3 | 2 | 1 |
| 1975 | 3 | 3 | 0 |
| 1974 | 2 | 0 | 2 |
| 1973 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 1971 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1970 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1958 | 6 | 0 | 6 |

- ALL Launches: 382
- Success: 357
- Failure: 25

39 launches in 2018, of which 38 were successful

48 consecutive successful launches between

- 2013 Dec  9 - Long March 4B - ziyuan yihao 03 xing
- 2016 Aug 31 - Long March 4C - Gao Fen 10

This is the script for China:
Provided by Jon Heller

```
select
    to_char(launch_date, 'YYYY') year
    ,count(*) launches
    ,sum(case when launch_status = 'success' then 1 else 0 end) success
    ,sum(case when launch_status = 'failure' then 1 else 0 end) failure
from launch
join site
    on launch.site_id = site.site_id
where
    launch_category in ('deep space', 'orbital') and
    (
        site_full_name like '%Jiuquan Space Center%' or
        site_full_name like '%Hainan%' or
        site_full_name like '%Xichang%' or
        site_full_name like '%China%' or
        site_full_name like '%zhongxin%'
    )
group by to_char(launch_date, 'YYYY')
order by year desc;
```

Answer (score 1):

Japan - JSR data:

| YEAR | LAUNCHES | SUCCESS | FAILURE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020 | 4 | 4 | 0 |
| 2019 | 2 | 2 | 0 |
| 2018 | 6 | 6 | 0 |
| 2017 | 7 | 6 | 1 |
| 2016 | 4 | 4 | 0 |
| 2015 | 4 | 4 | 0 |
| 2014 | 4 | 4 | 0 |
| 2013 | 3 | 3 | 0 |
| 2012 | 2 | 2 | 0 |
| 2011 | 3 | 3 | 0 |
| 2010 | 2 | 2 | 0 |
| 2009 | 3 | 3 | 0 |
| 2008 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2007 | 2 | 2 | 0 |
| 2006 | 6 | 6 | 0 |
| 2005 | 2 | 2 | 0 |
| 2004 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2003 | 3 | 2 | 1 |
| 2002 | 3 | 3 | 0 |
| 2001 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2000 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 1999 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 1998 | 2 | 2 | 0 |
| 1997 | 2 | 2 | 0 |
| 1996 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1995 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 1994 | 2 | 2 | 0 |
| 1993 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1992 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1991 | 2 | 2 | 0 |
| 1990 | 3 | 3 | 0 |
| 1989 | 2 | 2 | 0 |
| 1988 | 2 | 2 | 0 |
| 1987 | 3 | 3 | 0 |
| 1986 | 2 | 2 | 0 |
| 1985 | 2 | 2 | 0 |
| 1984 | 3 | 3 | 0 |
| 1983 | 3 | 3 | 0 |
| 1982 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1981 | 3 | 3 | 0 |
| 1980 | 2 | 2 | 0 |
| 1979 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 1978 | 3 | 3 | 0 |
| 1977 | 2 | 2 | 0 |
| 1976 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 1975 | 2 | 2 | 0 |
| 1974 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1973 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1972 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1971 | 2 | 2 | 0 |
| 1970 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 1969 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 1968 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1967 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 1966 | 2 | 0 | 2 |

- ALL Launches: 124
- Success: 112
- Failure: 12
- 7 launches in 2017
- 6 successful launches in 2018, 2017, 2006

36 consecutive successful launches between these two failed launches:

- 2003 Nov 29 - H-IIA-6F - IGS Optical-2
- 2017 Jan 14 - SS-520 - TRICOM-1

Answer (score 1):

UKRAINE - JSR data

| YEAR | LAUNCHES | SUCCESS | FAILURE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2017 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2015 | 2 | 2 | 0 |
| 2014 | 3 | 3 | 0 |
| 2013 | 4 | 3 | 1 |
| 2012 | 3 | 3 | 0 |
| 2011 | 6 | 6 | 0 |
| 2010 | 3 | 3 | 0 |
| 2009 | 6 | 6 | 0 |
| 2008 | 8 | 8 | 0 |
| 2007 | 5 | 4 | 1 |
| 2006 | 8 | 7 | 1 |
| 2005 | 5 | 5 | 0 |
| 2004 | 7 | 6 | 1 |
| 2003 | 3 | 3 | 0 |
| 2002 | 2 | 2 | 0 |
| 2001 | 6 | 6 | 0 |
| 2000 | 7 | 5 | 2 |
| 1999 | 5 | 5 | 0 |
| 1998 | 4 | 3 | 1 |
| 1997 | 3 | 2 | 1 |
| 1996 | 3 | 3 | 0 |
| 1995 | 4 | 4 | 0 |
| 1994 | 12 | 11 | 1 |
| 1992 | 8 | 7 | 1 |

- ALL Launches: 128 - in 29 years
- Success: 118
- Failure: 10
- 8 launches in 2008 - all of them successful

30 consecutive successful launches between these two failed launches
2007 Jan 30 - Zenit-3SL - NSS 8
2013 Feb  1 - Zenit-3SL - Intelsat IS-27

Answer (score 0):

Someone with a computer was kind enough to get this data for me:

ISRAEL:

```
site_full_name like '%Palmachim%'
```

| YEAR | LAUNCHES | SUCCESS | FAILURE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2016 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2014 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2010 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2007 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2004 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 2002 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1998 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 1995 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1990 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1988 | 1 | 1 | 0 |

- ALL Launches: 11 - in 23 years
- Success: 9
- Failure: 2

5 consecutive successful launches between 2007 and 2020

Answer (score 0):

Got data for USA, from JSR

| YEAR | LAUNCHES | SUCCESS | FAILURE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020 | 37 | 35 | 2 |
| 2019 | 27 | 27 | 0 |
| 2018 | 34 | 34 | 0 |
| 2017 | 30 | 29 | 1 |
| 2016 | 22 | 22 | 0 |
| 2015 | 20 | 18 | 2 |
| 2014 | 23 | 22 | 1 |
| 2013 | 19 | 19 | 0 |
| 2012 | 13 | 13 | 0 |
| 2011 | 18 | 17 | 1 |
| 2010 | 15 | 15 | 0 |
| 2009 | 24 | 23 | 1 |
| 2008 | 15 | 14 | 1 |
| 2007 | 19 | 17 | 2 |
| 2006 | 18 | 17 | 1 |
| 2005 | 12 | 12 | 0 |
| 2004 | 16 | 15 | 1 |
| 2003 | 23 | 23 | 0 |
| 2002 | 17 | 17 | 0 |
| 2001 | 22 | 21 | 1 |
| 2000 | 28 | 28 | 0 |
| 1999 | 31 | 27 | 4 |
| 1998 | 36 | 34 | 2 |
| 1997 | 38 | 37 | 1 |
| 1996 | 33 | 32 | 1 |
| 1995 | 30 | 26 | 4 |
| 1994 | 27 | 26 | 1 |
| 1993 | 25 | 23 | 2 |
| 1992 | 29 | 28 | 1 |
| 1991 | 19 | 17 | 2 |
| 1990 | 27 | 27 | 0 |
| 1989 | 18 | 18 | 0 |
| 1988 | 11 | 11 | 0 |
| 1987 | 9 | 8 | 1 |
| 1986 | 9 | 6 | 3 |
| 1985 | 18 | 17 | 1 |
| 1984 | 22 | 21 | 2 |
| 1983 | 22 | 22 | 1 |
| 1982 | 18 | 18 | 0 |
| 1981 | 19 | 17 | 3 |
| 1980 | 15 | 13 | 3 |
| 1979 | 16 | 16 | 1 |
| 1978 | 33 | 32 | 2 |
| 1977 | 26 | 23 | 3 |
| 1976 | 27 | 27 | 0 |
| 1975 | 30 | 27 | 4 |
| 1974 | 23 | 20 | 4 |
| 1973 | 25 | 23 | 3 |
| 1972 | 32 | 30 | 3 |
| 1971 | 34 | 29 | 6 |
| 1970 | 29 | 28 | 1 |
| 1969 | 41 | 38 | 6 |
| 1968 | 49 | 46 | 6 |
| 1967 | 64 | 60 | 5 |
| 1966 | 83 | 79 | 4 |
| 1965 | 77 | 69 | 8 |
| 1964 | 68 | 61 | 7 |
| 1963 | 47 | 38 | 9 |
| 1962 | 62 | 55 | 7 |
| 1961 | 45 | 33 | 12 |
| 1960 | 31 | 18 | 13 |
| 1959 | 19 | 10 | 9 |
| 1958 | 17 | 7 | 10 |
| 1957 | 1 | 0 | 1 |

Answer (score 0):

JSR data for India

| YEAR | LAUNCHES | SUCCESS | FAILURE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020 | 2 | 2 | 0 |
| 2019 | 6 | 6 | 0 |
| 2018 | 7 | 7 | 0 |
| 2017 | 5 | 4 | 1 |
| 2016 | 7 | 7 | 0 |
| 2015 | 5 | 5 | 0 |
| 2014 | 4 | 4 | 0 |
| 2013 | 3 | 3 | 0 |
| 2012 | 2 | 2 | 0 |
| 2011 | 3 | 3 | 0 |
| 2010 | 3 | 1 | 2 |
| 2009 | 2 | 2 | 0 |
| 2008 | 3 | 3 | 0 |
| 2007 | 3 | 2 | 1 |
| 2006 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 2005 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2004 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2003 | 2 | 2 | 0 |
| 2002 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2001 | 2 | 2 | 0 |
| 2000 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1999 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1998 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1997 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 1996 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1995 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1994 | 2 | 2 | 0 |
| 1993 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 1992 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1991 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1990 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1989 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1988 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 1987 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 1986 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1985 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1984 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1983 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1982 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1981 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 1980 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1979 | 1 | 0 | 1 |

- ALL Launches: 76
- Success: 65
- Failure: 11

28 consecutive successful launches between these two failed launches:

- 2010 Dec 25 - GSLV Mk I - GSAT-5 Prime
- 2017 Aug 31 - PSLV-XL - IRNSS-R1H

Answer (score 0):

EUROPE - JSR data:

| YEAR | LAUNCHES | SUCCESS | FAILURE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020 | 5 | 4 | 1 |
| 2019 | 6 | 5 | 1 |
| 2018 | 8 | 7 | 1 |
| 2017 | 9 | 9 | 0 |
| 2016 | 9 | 9 | 0 |
| 2015 | 9 | 9 | 0 |
| 2014 | 7 | 7 | 0 |
| 2013 | 5 | 5 | 0 |
| 2012 | 8 | 8 | 0 |
| 2011 | 5 | 5 | 0 |
| 2010 | 6 | 6 | 0 |
| 2009 | 7 | 7 | 0 |
| 2008 | 6 | 6 | 0 |
| 2007 | 6 | 6 | 0 |
| 2006 | 5 | 5 | 0 |
| 2005 | 5 | 5 | 0 |
| 2004 | 3 | 3 | 0 |
| 2003 | 4 | 4 | 0 |
| 2002 | 12 | 11 | 1 |
| 2001 | 8 | 7 | 1 |
| 2000 | 12 | 12 | 0 |
| 1999 | 10 | 10 | 0 |
| 1998 | 11 | 11 | 0 |
| 1997 | 12 | 11 | 1 |
| 1996 | 11 | 10 | 1 |
| 1995 | 11 | 11 | 0 |
| 1994 | 8 | 6 | 2 |
| 1993 | 7 | 7 | 0 |
| 1992 | 7 | 7 | 0 |
| 1991 | 8 | 8 | 0 |
| 1990 | 6 | 5 | 1 |
| 1989 | 7 | 7 | 0 |
| 1988 | 7 | 7 | 0 |
| 1987 | 2 | 2 | 0 |
| 1986 | 3 | 2 | 1 |
| 1985 | 4 | 3 | 1 |
| 1984 | 4 | 4 | 0 |
| 1983 | 2 | 2 | 0 |
| 1982 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 1981 | 2 | 2 | 0 |
| 1980 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 1979 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1978 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1977 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1976 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1975 | 3 | 3 | 0 |
| 1974 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1973 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 1972 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1971 | 3 | 1 | 2 |
| 1970 | 2 | 2 | 0 |
| 1969 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1968 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1967 | 2 | 2 | 0 |
| 1966 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1965 | 1 | 1 | 0 |

- ALL Launches: 283
- Success: 266
- Failure: 17
- 12 launches in 1997, 2000 and 2002
- 12 successful launches in 2000

95 successful launches between thsese two failed launches:

- 2002 Dec 11 - Hot Bird 7 - Ariane 5ECA
- 2018 Jan 25 - Ariane 5ECA - Al Yah 3