# Number of China orbital launches by year

Tags: launch, statistics

I've also posted the numbers below [as a temporary answer here](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/49176/12102) but I don't know if they are right so I'll also ask this as a question.

How many orbital launches did China make every year?

I got some data from Wikipedia, from pages like this one:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2019_in_spaceflight#Orbital_launch_statistics

But there is no data for years 2000 and before

Launches - succesfull - failures - partial failures

- 2019 - 34 - 32 - 2 - 0
- 2018 - 39 - 38 - 1 - 0
- 2017 - 18 - 16 - 1 - 1
- 2016 - 22 - 20 - 1 - 1
- 2015 - 19 - 19 - 0 - 0
- 2014 - 16 - 16 - 0 - 0
- 2013 - 15 - 14 - 1 - 0
- 2012 - 19 - 19 - 0 - 0
- 2011 - 19 - 18 - 1 - 0
- 2010 - 15 - 15 - 0 - 0
- 2009 - 6 - 5 - 0 - 1
- 2008 - 11 - 11 - 0 - 0
- 2007 - 10 - 10 - 0 - 0
- 2006 - 6 - 6 - 0 - 0
- 2005 - 5 - 5 - 0 - 0
- 2004 - 8 - 8 - 0 - 0
- 2003 - 7 - 6 - 1 - 0
- 2002 - 5 - 4 - 1 - 0
- 2001 - 1 - 1 - 0 - 0

Comment: As discussed previously, this question covers this off for all countries. Having separate ones for each country just makes duplication [Number of launches by year, by country](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/49158/number-of-launches-by-year-by-country)

Comment: The answer to that question is too long and unreadable - it takes a lot of scrolling to get to the country you might be interested about. I think it is much better to close that question and to allow separate questions for individual countries, like this one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below are the number of orbital and deep space launches from China.

| YEAR | LAUNCHES | SUCCESS | FAILURE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2016 | 22 | 21 | 1 |
| 2015 | 19 | 19 | 0 |
| 2014 | 16 | 16 | 0 |
| 2013 | 15 | 14 | 1 |
| 2012 | 19 | 19 | 0 |
| 2011 | 19 | 18 | 1 |
| 2010 | 15 | 15 | 0 |
| 2009 | 6 | 5 | 1 |
| 2008 | 11 | 11 | 0 |
| 2007 | 10 | 10 | 0 |
| 2006 | 6 | 6 | 0 |
| 2005 | 6 | 5 | 1 |
| 2004 | 8 | 8 | 0 |
| 2003 | 7 | 6 | 1 |
| 2002 | 5 | 4 | 1 |
| 2001 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2000 | 5 | 5 | 0 |
| 1999 | 4 | 4 | 0 |
| 1998 | 6 | 6 | 0 |
| 1997 | 6 | 6 | 0 |
| 1996 | 4 | 2 | 2 |
| 1995 | 3 | 2 | 1 |
| 1994 | 5 | 5 | 0 |
| 1993 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1992 | 4 | 3 | 1 |
| 1991 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1990 | 5 | 5 | 0 |
| 1988 | 4 | 4 | 0 |
| 1987 | 2 | 2 | 0 |
| 1986 | 2 | 2 | 0 |
| 1985 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1984 | 3 | 3 | 0 |
| 1983 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1982 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1981 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1979 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 1978 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1976 | 3 | 2 | 1 |
| 1975 | 3 | 3 | 0 |
| 1974 | 2 | 0 | 2 |
| 1973 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 1971 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1970 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1958 | 6 | 0 | 6 |

The data is based on a SQL interface to the 2017 JSR Launch Vehicle Database, as described in my answer [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/48390/33395). These numbers are pretty close to the numbers from Wikipedia, but not exact matches. These questions are always more complicated than we'd like them to be and depend on how we define things like space and success.

The results are based on the below SQL query. If you want to verify the results or compare them to another source, replace the items in the SELECT clause with `*` and remove the GROUP BY and ORDER BY lines to get the full details.

```
select
    to_char(launch_date, 'YYYY') year
    ,count(*) launches
    ,sum(case when launch_status = 'success' then 1 else 0 end) success
    ,sum(case when launch_status = 'failure' then 1 else 0 end) failure
from launch
join site
    on launch.site_id = site.site_id
where
    launch_category in ('deep space', 'orbital') and
    (
        site_full_name like '%Jiuquan Space Center%' or
        site_full_name like '%Hainan%' or
        site_full_name like '%Xichang%' or
        site_full_name like '%China%' or
        site_full_name like '%zhongxin%'
    )
group by to_char(launch_date, 'YYYY')
order by year desc;
```

Comment: I managed to find the landing site for Israel but I can't figure how to find the Ukraine launches, which used various locations outside Ukraine to launch their rockets

Comment: I think the following question is interesting: "What is the biggest number of consecutive successful American orbital launches?" - I am not allowed to ask questions but if you would ask the question and then answer your own question then I will put a bounty of 100 points to it and give the bounty to you. Can I ask you to please ask this question?

Comment: @JoeJobs I'm not comfortable asking questions for other people since there's a lot of room for error. And it might also be difficult to know exactly what is an "American" launch. It's relatively easy to categorize launches by site, but it's difficult to categorize them by their agency's country since there are so many agencies and some launches have multiple agencies involved.

Comment: Meanwhile I think I found a missing launch in the database: 24 January 1994 - Ariane 4 - Eutelsat 2F5 - Türksat-1A, the launch_id should have been 65399 - where can I report such errors? - the launch is listed here - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1994_in_spaceflight

Comment: Meanwhile I reported the item to Jonathan McDowell and he said the item is not missing in his database. Then why is it missing from your openspace database? Try "select * from launch where launch_id in (65398, 65399); and you will get the launches before and after that launch - 20 and 25 January 1994

Comment: Also this launch - 25 May 1994 - Tsyklon-3 - Tselina - launch_id should be 65428

Comment: Jonathan McDowell answered again and said the data might be missing in the 2017 version of the database

Comment: @JoeJobs Thanks for looking that up and for reporting it. I hope to build a better database off of his improved GCAT data source some day; that ought to improve the data and offer many new features.

Answer (score 0):

I will update the data adding years 2017 and after:

| YEAR | LAUNCHES | SUCCESS | FAILURE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020 | 37 | 33 | 4 |
| 2019 | 34 | 32 | 2 |
| 2018 | 39 | 38 | 1 |
| 2017 | 18 | 16 | 2 |
| 2016 | 22 | 21 | 1 |
| 2015 | 19 | 19 | 0 |
| 2014 | 16 | 16 | 0 |
| 2013 | 15 | 14 | 1 |
| 2012 | 19 | 19 | 0 |
| 2011 | 19 | 18 | 1 |
| 2010 | 15 | 15 | 0 |
| 2009 | 6 | 5 | 1 |
| 2008 | 11 | 11 | 0 |
| 2007 | 10 | 10 | 0 |
| 2006 | 6 | 6 | 0 |
| 2005 | 6 | 5 | 1 |
| 2004 | 8 | 8 | 0 |
| 2003 | 7 | 6 | 1 |
| 2002 | 5 | 4 | 1 |
| 2001 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2000 | 5 | 5 | 0 |
| 1999 | 4 | 4 | 0 |
| 1998 | 6 | 6 | 0 |
| 1997 | 6 | 6 | 0 |
| 1996 | 4 | 2 | 2 |
| 1995 | 3 | 2 | 1 |
| 1994 | 5 | 5 | 0 |
| 1993 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1992 | 4 | 3 | 1 |
| 1991 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1990 | 5 | 5 | 0 |
| 1988 | 4 | 4 | 0 |
| 1987 | 2 | 2 | 0 |
| 1986 | 2 | 2 | 0 |
| 1985 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1984 | 3 | 3 | 0 |
| 1983 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1982 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1981 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1979 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 1978 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1976 | 3 | 2 | 1 |
| 1975 | 3 | 3 | 0 |
| 1974 | 2 | 0 | 2 |
| 1973 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 1971 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1970 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1958 | 6 | 0 | 6 |