# When was the first time for each of these USA states that it launched a rocket into orbit?

Tags: launch, orbit, spaceflight-firsts, statistics

Only five states and territories had launches that got into orbit: Florida, California, Virginia, Alaska and Marshall Islands

But when was the first time for each of those  states that a launched rocket reached orbit?

[Jon Heller said he would answer this question using his great SQL tools.](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/48375/number-of-satellites-launched-per-year/48410?noredirect=1#comment159120_48410)

Florida is the most easy because it had the first launch of a USA satellite.

- Florida - 1 February 1958 - Explorer 1

For California I could only find [Athena I](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Athena_I) rocket launching Lewis satellite at 23 August 1997

Related question:

- [US states with most space launches?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/48710/us-states-with-most-space-launches)

Comment: All the states are firmly affixed to the surface of the Earth.

Comment: If you mean "an astronaut from each USA state", that's something you should be able to easily research on your own. Wikipedia has [time-ordered lists of all crewed spaceflights.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_human_spaceflights,_1961–1970)

Comment: Space Exploration, where "research effort" is a slogan.

Comment: Jon Heller said he would answer with a quick SQL

Comment: Your edit hasn't helped clarify the question. Are you asking about launch sites in different states, rocket manufacturers based in different states, or what?

Comment: Here's a list of launch sites. Maybe you could do a little research and give us the answer. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_rocket_launch_sites

Comment: Florida Had To.  Texas was getting close, and **we cannot allow a [missile gap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Missile_gap)**.   Yeah, states were all competitive like that and not on the same team.   OK that was being sarcastic, but now I realize it doesn't work when states today actually aren't on the same team.  No, it wasn't like that, then.  it was Team America against the Soviets, end of subject.

Comment: @JoeJobs if this is a follow-up to a comment ("... said they would answer..."), then you should have included a link to that comment within your question to alert people that an answer was imminent. `-1` for not including relevant information until after being questioned about it, and then only putting it in a comment and not the post itself.

Comment: I had no idea I have to point to such personal conversations into the text of the question. I thought it's all about how clear the question is, and I think the question is quite clear now. I really can't understand what is missing. I also inclduded the link in the question now. Is there anything wrong with the question now? I am asking simply because I have no idea what is wrong with the question to stay closed. I have no idea what to do to make even more clear because it looks really clear to me.

Comment: I am also willing to put a 300 points bounty for this question if it will be opened

Comment: Afaik most of them never launched. USA rocket launches happen from southern states to spare some hundreds m/s delta v by the rotation of the Earth. But all of them paid into the federal budget from which the launches are financed, probably all of them have companies working in their space programs, and all of them profited from them.

Comment: True. California, Florida, Virginia, Alaska and Marshal Islands. But the question is when they launched first time?

Comment: I´ve changed the text of the question, I have no idea how to make it more clear now. There is a "reopen" button but I don't want to use it. Can anyone take a look?

Answer (score 3):

Ok, did some googling…

Florida: Explorer 1, 2/1/1958

California: Discover 1, 2/28/1959

Virginia: Explorer 9, 2/15/1961

Marshall Islands (Kwajalein): HETE-2, 10/9/2000

Alaska (Kodiac): Starshine 3, 9/30/2001

And for extra credit

California has a second launch site at Mojave and Virgin Orbit launched Elana 20 on 1/17/2021. Not a first for California, but a new launch site is always a big deal.